# asp.net application to html5/css3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, css

I have an asp.net application made in VisualStudio2008 and I want to have a similar kind of application for mobile users and I want to use HTML5 and css3 for that but I dont know how to deal with code-behind part can anyone help?

Comment: I want an application that can work in all the mobiles like windows android

Answer (score 1):

You can expose the logic/code in code behind through web services,*(better if they are RESTful)*, and then consume those services through your client side code ([jQuery](http://jquery.com/))

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into something like Nustache (Mustache for .NET).

A better option would be to reproach your front-end markup so that it's responsive. A great option would be to use something like Twitter Bootstrap or Zurb's Foundation framework.

Comment: Eventually, more people will catch on. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery mobile for your project [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/413099/HTML5-jQuery-Mobile-and-ASP-NET-MVC-4-Using-the-Vi) is article maybe help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Twitter Bootstrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/. It really is the best option and will make creating a responsive mobile and desktop site a breeze.